# Export Apk file of Android uses Facebook Sdk as Linked Library

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

i was using facebook sdk as linked library from my own android project, when i deploy it on emulator or to android device from usb by eclipse then all is ok. But i want to export it as  .apk file and i want to deploy the device directly but the result is **Application not installed** is it because of missing library? How can i resolve it? Thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 the result is Application not installed is it because of missing library?
```

No, missing the library should not result in the app being unable to install.

Most probably what is happening is that you still have the debug signed app on your device.

When you click the run button in eclipse it signs the APK with a special "debug" key. When you export it for real it gets signed with your actual release key.

As far as the Android System is concerned your 2 apks are not the "same app" because they are signed with different keys, that is why it will not allow one to replace the other.

The fix is to uninstall the previous apk from your device before installing the newly exported one.

You can accomplish that buy going to Settings->Manage Apps and finding your app and uninstalling it, or via adb by using this command:

```
adb uninstall the.package.name.for.your.application
```

Let this also serve as a learning experience, if you ever lose your release key, then your users will not be able to install new versions of your application without uninstalling the previous versions first. Backup your release keys =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i removed as you said and tried to deploy again as signed and unsigned apk two of them says Application Not Installed again...

Comment: Restarted again and i saw that there was associated package loaded before used the same shared library after removing it run Thank you...